# How to send a password with a $ symbol in Expect Script

Tags: bash, authentication, ssh, expect, remote-server

I have an expect script that I need to login to a remote system and execute commands. This script works with the exception of providing the password to the root account. The root password contains a dollar sign that I cannot seem to get to work. Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 3
set username "root"
set password "Pas$word"
set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
log_user 0

send_user "\n#####\n# $hostname\n#####\n"

spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$hostname

expect {
    timeout { send_user "\nFailed to get password prompt\n"; exit 1 }
    eof { send_user "\nSSH failure for $hostname\n"; exit 1 }
    "*assword"
}

send "$password\r"

expect {
    timeout { send_user "\nLogin failed. Password incorrect.\n"; exit 1}
    "*\$ "
}

send_user "\nPassword is correct\n"

expect "$ " { send "ls" }
```

I have verified this works when providing credentials whose passwords don't contain the dollar sign, but I can't get it to work with the root account. It always produces the `Login failed. Password incorrect` timeout error. Changing the password is not an option. I have tried to supply the `\` escape character in the password definition like so:

```
set password "Pas\$word"
```

And I get the same results... any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**
As I said. I already tried to escape the $ character. But to clarify, I added a print statement for the password when the script starts up to verify the variable contains the password correctly... Here is the change:

```
set password "Pas\$word"
...
send_user "\n#####\n# $hostname\n#####\n"
send_user "Using password: $password\n"
...
```

Here is the console output:

```
njozwiak@ubuntu:~$ ./ssh_ls.sh 192.168.5.93

#####
# 192.168.5.93
#####
Using password: Pas$word

Login failed. Password incorrect.
```

Comment: Get rid of the quotes wherever you are using set. Checkout my answer.

Comment: I would think `set password {Pas$word}` should be sufficient. Run your script with `expect -d ssh-ls.sh` to see what's happening in the background.

Answer (score 9):

Try escaping the backslash, that is

```
Pas$word
```

becomes

```
Pas\\\$word
```

This is a common problem with scripting (even with PHP, Python) where a string gets unescaped twice or even more times!

A full-blown example how I use *[expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)* with SFTP, inside a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=mysftp.dmz
port=22
username=john

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn sftp -C -oPort=$port $username@$host
expect "password:"
send "Pas\\\$word\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get data.txt\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF
```

Comment: Why do we need three backslashes instead of one?

Comment: @zyy: Because the "string gets unescaped **twice**" during the process: 
1. unescape("Pas\\\$word") => "Pas\$word",
2. unescape("Pas\$word") => "Pas$word"

Comment: Thanks, I will check.

Answer (score 8):

I've found a makeshift solution for this. I'm sure this problem solved long ago, just mentioning how I solved mine:

Actual password:
`Pas$word`

Assign to variable password:
`set password {Pas\$word}`

In TCL(or expect in your code), grouping words within double braces {} disables substitution within the braces, thus your password will be stored as:
`Pas\$word`
Now in the end, when you send password via expect `Pas\$word` will be translated as `Pas$word` which is the actual password.

But the problem is if the password is unknown, for example, password is in an encrypted file or has to be taken as user input. I was looking for this type of cases where I don't know where and how many $ sings are in the password.

Comment: makeshift? it's GENIUS!

Comment: Genius! But just letting people who were trying to escape all bash symbols, you don't need to escape `@`

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to get this working by just escaping the dollar sign.  I did have luck by using \x to specify the hex value for the dollar sign.

set password "Pas\x24word"

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I had the same issue, I know it's an old question but for whoever is also still looking for a quick solution:

```
set CorrectedPassword [ string map -nocase { "\$" "\\\$" } $MyPassword ]
```

The $CorrectedPassword is then accepted by the login procedure. The -nocase is not needed, but I find it safer to include by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to pass fileName with "$" in expect script and following worked for me

```
filePath=$(echo -n $filePath | sed -e 's/\$/\\\$/g')
```

Answer (score 1):

I used below and it worked for me :

```
send \"Pas\\\$word\"
```

Answer (score -1):

This should definitely help -

```
set username root
set password Pas\$word
```

**Get rid of the quotes.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: No quotes produces the same results as with quotes. `Login failed. Password incorrect.`

Comment: Note that without the quotes, the password is displayed the same from the console output as with quotes. "Using password: Pas$word"

Comment: @njozwiak - What about set username root? Did you get rid of the quotes there too?

Comment: @njozwiak - I'm saying this because I have just tried that in my machine and it's working quite fine. :)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem recently. This worked for me:

$ PASS="pa\$\$word"; somecommand --user uname --password $PASS

Notice double quotes and the semicolon.

Comment: 1) Your solution is for `pa$$word`, not for `pas$word`, and 
2) with _expect_ you need to escape the string twice: `pas\\\$word`